# Java repeated character regex with condition

Tags: java, regex, repeat

I have large database. I want to check my database capitalize errors. I use this pattern for repeated chars. Pattern works but i need to start and end condition with string.

**Pattern:**

```
(\w)\1+
```

**Target String:**

```
Javaaa
```

result: **aaa**

I want to **add condition to regex**; Start with **Ja** and end with **a*. Result **only must be repetead** characters.

> (I dont want to control programmatically only regex do this if its possible
>
> (I'm do this with `String.replaceAll(regex, string)` not to
>   `Pattern or Matcher` class)

Comment: you mean this? `\\bJa\\w*(\\w)\\1+\\w*a\\b`

Comment: this regex result select all. This have condition but result must be aaa if target string Prooo and regex \\bPro\\w*(\\w)\\1+\\w*o\\b then result must be ooo. Your regex result word all

Comment: capture the repeated part, `\\bJa\\w*((\\w)\\2+)\\w*a\\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookahead anchored at the leading word boundary:

```
\b(?=Ja\w*a\b)\w*?((\w)\2+)\w*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO7uL4/1)

Details:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?=Ja\w*a\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires the whole word to start with `Ja`, then it can have 0+ word characters and end with `a`
- `\w*?` - 0+ word characters but as few as possible
- `((\w)\2+)` - Group 1 matching identical consecutive characters
- `\w*` - any remaining word characters (0 or more)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

The result you are seeking is in Group 1.

```
String s = "Prooo\nJavaaa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?=Ja\\w*a\\b)\\w*?((\\w)\\2+)\\w*\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/zaGHWP).

Comment: I dont want it because i have large capitalize list have many regex and i use String.replaceAll(regex, string) methods. For example in my list: [ ]{1,}[.]{1,}[ ]{1,}###. (### is splitter).

Comment: What is the trouble then? Replace with `$1`. Are the strings standalone? If they are, just use `^` instead of the leading word boundary, and `$` instead of a trailing word boundary. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC7pR3/1).

Comment: Yes standalone. For example i want this; In word Javaaa after regex Java if word Prooo after regex Pro. If word Theee do not the anything. I want to only you make the words I have set via String.replaceAll(regex, string) methods.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Finally `String s = "Javaaa"` String.replaceAll() methods after result is : Java *with your regex* is it possible?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you need. Please let know what variables are known.

Comment: Your demo link stdout is: *Java* not aaa is it possible? But regex must be have start Ja end a conditions :)

Comment: The output is `aaa`, you want it to be `Java`? Like [this](http://ideone.com/WAlMP7)?

Answer (score 1):

Another code example (inspired from @Wiktor Stribizew's code ) as per your expected input and output format.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String[] input =
        { "Javaaa", "Javaaaaaaaaa", "Javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "Paoooo", "Paoooooooo", "Paooooooooxxxxxxxxx" };
    for ( String str : input )
    {

        System.out.println( "Target String :" + str );
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "((.)\\2+)" );
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( str );
        while ( matcher.find() )
        {
            System.out.println( "result: " + matcher.group() );
        }
        System.out.println( "---------------------" );
    }
    System.out.println( "Finish" );
}
```

**Output:**

```
Target String :Javaaa
result: aaa
---------------------
Target String :Javaaaaaaaaa
result: aaaaaaaaa
---------------------
Target String :Javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
result: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
---------------------
Target String :Paoooo
result: oooo
---------------------
Target String :Paoooooooo
result: oooooooo
---------------------
Target String :Paooooooooxxxxxxxxx
result: oooooooo
result: xxxxxxxxx
---------------------
Finish
```

Comment: I dont want it because i have large capitalize list have many regex and i use String.replaceAll(regex, string) methods. For example in my list: [ ]{1,}[.]{1,}[ ]{1,}###. (### is splitter).